# WcfAjaxEnabled - Postback

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wcf

I've a wcf ajax enabled hosted in a web site (it's a web chat).

For some reason, when I need to execute a postback, my wcf service works in unexpectedly way (such as big delay in a call, work off, and so on..).

The oddity occurs when I try to call some wcf function through javascript from protected page too (Many page are protected by web config with authentication mode=form).

Are the above issue caused from the same reason? But which can it be the reason?

EDIT:

I notice that the above problems occurs only when my web site contains global asax file with sessionStart and SessionEnd event handlers (it's true even when those event handlers are empty, namely without any instrunction).

@EDIT:
Ok, issue about postback is due to devExpress control (captcha). If I use a simple button for doing some postabck all works fine. Maybe that component injects some bad script in my page, I've not idea. 
So, remain questione about access to protected page by login only. It's important to know that login issue occurs only on production site where login page is placed on internal (nested) application, while on test site where login mechanism is on the same application all works fine. 
However, in this moment I solved by changing login logic for chat access. I've removed the protection in web config for that chat admin page and I check user credential on its init event. If it's not logged, then I execute a simple redirect to login page and all works correctly.

@@EDIT
Well, I found the exact cause and solved it. Please, take a look here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlightws/archive/2009/09/30/having-a-pollingduplex-service-and-any-other-wcf-service-in-the-same-website-causes-silverlight-calls-to-be-slow.aspx

Comment: Session_Start and Session_End shouldn't affect anything unless you are doing some time-consuming process in there.

Comment: Session_Start and Session_End doesn't contains any code. however, my wcf ajax enabled implements long polling (through exchange of thread signal with eventWaitHandle). I don't know if this can influence some bad behavior.. It's very strange.

Comment: Can you please put your last edit in an answer, and summarize the details of the link as well? This way others can benefit if they land on your question!